# Integrate Magento with SalesForce

Tags: webservices

What is the best (free) way to integrate salesforce with magento?
Basically we want to be able to import the contacts of anyone who buys from our page into salesforce. 
- I could not find any useful resource other than few apps(paid) on the appexchange

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Directly inserting contact would be more work.

If you want to do it quickly with less effort then try and use Web to lead

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm

If you want to insert into contact and ready to take integration effort then you should call SFDC api and insert contact using SOAP or REST call.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can check this plugin
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/salesforce/Magento-Salesforce-Connector.html
and salesforce free app here 
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DY0BJEA1

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at http://www.powersync.biz

**Customer Features are:**

1. Bi-directional sync
2. Lead and Contact/Account support
3. Lead assignment rule support
4. B2B and B2C support (person accounts)
5. Auto-merge of duplicates
6. Multi-store setup support (global and per website customers in Magento)
7. Ability to limit sync based on Customer Group
8. Advanced Account matching
9. Ability to integrate with a single Account
10. Newsletter subscriber integration support
11. Contact Us form integration
12. Fully customizable mappings for all objects

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the rest and soap api but its a time consuming process.Based on my research go for built-in extension.It will save your time and money.You will find lots of vendor but i95devsalesforce features are good and price is fewer than other vendor..
https://store.i95dev.com/magento-salesforce-crm-connect.html

Answer (score -1):

The best way to make that happen is using this great magento extension called "MagForce" https://products.crunchyconsulting.com/crunchy-products/crunchy-magforce.html

Automatic Opportunity creation order process
Mass Actions for Orders to create them in Salesforce
Flexibility in creating/updating Contacts in Salesforce
Automatic Lead/Contact creation during Magento user account creation
Create Products in Salesforce from Order
Assign Products to Opportunities automatically
Assign Contacts to Opportunities automatically

Comment: James could you explain what's so great about this extension or share us your experience ? Not doing so provides little more info than advertising, which would get removed.